# Table contains file names and sizes... Need a query to return count of each file type and total sum size of each type

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have a table that has a file name column and a file size column.
I'd like to generate a report that counts how many of each file type there is and how much space the sum of each file type is consuming. Using substring_index I can return just the file extension in one column and the file size in the next, then I believe I can use COUNT(*) and SUM and GROUP BY in some proper fashion to get the results... but I can't seem to sort it out...

```
SELECT
 substring_index(FILE_NAME,'.',-1),
 FILE_SIZE
FROM FILES
GROUP BY FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your grouping is too specific.  Try this:

```
SELECT
 substring_index(FILE_NAME,'.',-1) AS extension,
 SUM(FILE_SIZE)
FROM FILES
GROUP BY extension
```